# Implementing jQuery Mobile HTML/CSS pages into Rails-developed website

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

1) I've got a simple set of HTML/CSS pages developed with jQuery Mobile for enhancement, etc. Everything works fine with just these pages on their own. The files are:

The files include:

- HTML (all file names are different from regular site page names)
- CSS
- image files - jpg, png, etc.
- jQuery / jQuery Mobile libraries

Tiny bit of embedded Javascript but other than JQ/JQM no other separate JS files.

2) Company has website developed in Rails, with the typical directory structure -- app, controller, helpers, etc.

Yesterday, I tried to upload my pages/images/resources/etc to the app folder, and entire website just wouldn't load -- all blank. Moreover, I tried just uploading 1 HTML file + its css, resources, etc. to the app folder, and:

- the rest of the site loaded but some elements were affected by CSS despite different class names
- that specific HTML file would not load.

Here are my questions.

1. How would you upload these pages to the Rails site? (and if any Rails files need to be updated)
2. How would you link to these mobile pages, and in particular, place a link on the main site page to these pages?
3. Any ideas on why my CSS, despite having different class names, seems to affect other elements on the site?

I do not know anything at all about Ruby or Ruby on Rails.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading to the public folder instead. The app folder is used so Rails can serve dynamic pages using the MVC design pattern. Make sure you reference all your CSS and Javascript correctly from the public folder inside your HTML.

Comment: Thank you so much! Accessing regular HTML files in that folder seems to work just fine. Followup question: Do I need to update other files in other places to get it to work (e.g. if Rails has some sort of directory file or something) or can I just drag and drop it in?